# Is it possible to install disks in raid post installation?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, lenovo, raid

I have just received my new Ubuntu 22.04 workstation from Lenovo.
It has 2 1TB disks, that I want to use in RAID 1 for `/`, and 4 2TB disks that I want to use in RAID 5 for `/home`.
However the machine arrived with Ubuntu already "almost set up", I had only to chose username, there was no disk management.
So now, I have a full desktop with one of the 1TB disk with 3 partitions: two system ones (UEFI and PQSERVICE) and the main space interelly allocated to UBuntu mounted on /.
The other 5 disks are unmounted and unpartitioned.

Can I go from this situation to my required disk set up? Or do I need to reinstall ubuntu from scratch?
What would I loose in installing from a standard Ubuntu image compared to use the Lenovo oem provided one ?

Comment: Possible, yes ... But, easier and cleaner to fresh install and configure raid devices to your liking since it's a new machine  ... If it's shipped with Ubuntu, then all drivers you need (if any) should be provided by Lenovo for Ubuntu (check first) ... The "PQSERVICE" (you can back it up if you want) partition as I understand it is used to bring your system back to this state that you want to change ... So, basically there shouldn't be anything you will lose if you fresh install I think ... Read their website on special installation notes and info (if any) first.